# I want use version '1.1.0' of `Alamofire-SwiftyJSON`

Tags: xcode, swift, cocoapods, alamofire, swifty-json

I want use version '1.1.0' of `Alamofire-SwiftyJSON`

My Podfile is:

```
pod 'Alamofire', :git => 'https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git', :tag => '1.2.3'
pod 'SwiftyJSON', :git => 'https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON.git', :tag => '2.2.0'
pod 'Alamofire-SwiftyJSON', :git => "https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/Alamofire-SwiftyJSON.git", :tag => '1.1.0'
```

and I got follow error:

```
Analyzing dependencies
Pre-downloading: `Alamofire` from `https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git`, tag `1.2.3`
Pre-downloading: `Alamofire-SwiftyJSON` from `https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/Alamofire-SwiftyJSON.git`, tag `1.1.0`
[!] Unable to find a specification for 'Alamofire-SwiftyJSON'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a normal situation. The `Alamofire-SwiftyJSON` repository does not have a podspec into its repo at the tag `1.1.0` and no pod has been push to the cocoapod trunk.

You will have to fork the project, and add the `Alamofire-SwiftyJSON.podspec` to the root by yourself. An example of what it should look like:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name        = "Alamofire-SwiftyJSON"
  s.version     = "1.1.0"
  s.summary     = "Alamofire extension for serialize NSData to SwiftyJSON "
  s.homepage    = "https://github.com/[your github name]/Alamofire-SwiftyJSON"
  s.license     = { :type => "MIT" }

  s.requires_arc = true
  s.osx.deployment_target = "10.9"
  s.ios.deployment_target = "8.0"
  s.source   = { :git => "https://github.com/[your github name]/Alamofire-SwiftyJSON.git", :tag => s.version }
  s.source_files = "Source/*.swift"
  s.dependency 'Alamofire', '1.3'
  s.dependency 'SwiftyJSON', '2.2.0'
end
```